# Microsoft SQL container without a volume has persistent storage

Tags: sql-server, docker, containers

I'm using Portainer and deployed a Mirosoft SQL Server container using the "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest" image with default settings, save for the "EULA" and sa password env. variables.

I was surprised to see there was no volume attached to the container when I inspected it after it was deployed. To see if its data would persist, I connected to the server, created a database and then restarted the container. The database was still there after the restart.

As far as I know a container without a persistent storage, in the face of a volume, would lose any changes / data that is not part of its default configuration on stop/restart.

So how can the SQL server still have my database if it doesn't have a volume attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container keeps its data on restart. (docker stop / start / restart command).

It's when you delete it (docker rm command) that it will drop the data.

Comment: Is there any other situation where the data might be lost without a volume? Assuming the container is not deleted.

Comment: Yes, when you uninstall docker (or the associated VM if you're on Windows 10), or your update the container version